# Pandas groupby object unique count performance

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset of transaction data which looks like:

`| cust_no | acct_no | trans_id | product_id | ..... |`

I try several way to count how many unique accounts per customer, and how many unique products customer buy etc.

- Method 1.a

`transaction_df[['cust_no','acct_no']].groupby('cust_no')['acct_no'].nunique()`

which runs average 91.5ms

- Method 1.b

`transaction_df.groupby('cust_no')['acct_no'].nunique()`

which runs average 85.5ms

- Method 2.a

`transaction_df[['cust_no','acct_no']].groupby(['cust_no','acct_no']).size().groupby('cust_no').size()`

which runs 61.5ms

- Method 2.a

`transaction_df.groupby(['cust_no','acct_no']).size().groupby('cust_no').size()`

which runs 55.3ms

I have two question:

1. why is the the DataFrame after slicing run slower, i.e. `transaction_df[['cust_no','acct_no']]` is slower than just `transaction_df`?
2. why `.nunique()` method is much slower than just stack up two `groupby`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Slicing requires memory assignment and/or a copy of the object depending on the operation.  Here you're creating a new DataFrame before starting your operations.

2) `nunique` is going to either implement logic for or directly call a `set`, which runs in O(N) time.  `size` will run O(1)

Knowing prior structural information about your dataset can help you optimize function selection as you're experimenting with here.  Read into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity if you're interested